# Rudin's Proof of the Riesz Representation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

I am having trouble understanding step III in Rudin's proof of the Riesz Representation theorem:

[image]

I'm not going to define any of the symbols that occur in the picture or provided any of the background details, so don't complain about there not being enough details for you to answer the question and acquire more points. This question is for those who have a copy of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.

Obviously if $K$ is compact set contained in the open set $V$, then $\mu(K) \le \mu(V)$ for every $K \subseteq V$, and so $\mu(V)$ is an upper bound for $\{\mu(K) \mid K \subseteq V, K \mbox{ is compact } \}$. Hence, $\sup \{\mu(K) \mid K \subseteq V, K \mbox{ is compact } \} \le \mu(V)$....However, I don't know how to get the reverse inequality...Perhaps it's due to the fact that I've already spent an entire (on and off) working through the proof, so that my brain is fried...What I don't understand is, which inequality is Rudin proving? I presume it's the one I'm having trouble with. I don't understand how considering any open set $W$ that contains $\mbox{supp} (f)$ helps show the other inequality

EDIT:

For those who find my post unclear, here is the cliffsnotes version:

Rudin is proving that $ \mu(V) = \sup \{\mu(K) \mid K \subseteq V, K \mbox{ is compact } \}$; showing $\sup \{\mu(K) \mid K \subseteq V, K \mbox{ is compact } \} \le \mu(V)$ is trivial; and I'm wondering how to get the other inequality.

Comment: Even if I did want to get up, walk over to my library and grab Rudin's book, your question would be unclear.

Comment: @uniquesolution Would you mind being more specific on how it is unclear? I think I spelled it out clearly, provided you have a copy of Rudin before: Rudin is proving that $ \mu(V) = \sup \{\mu(K) \mid K \subseteq V, K \mbox{ is compact } \}$; showing $\sup \{\mu(K) \mid K \subseteq V, K \mbox{ is compact } \} \le \mu(V)$ is trivial; and I'm wondering how to get the other inequality. How is that not clear?

Comment: "I am wondering how to get the other inequality" is NOT a question, but a statement. This is how much it is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it *is* unclear. My copy of the book is missing - I  had no idea what was being proved until your edit. Having clarified that, what step do you have a problem with?

(i) If $\alpha < \mu(V)$ there exists $K\subset V$ with $\mu(K)>\alpha$.

(ii) It follows that $\sup_K\mu(K)\ge\mu(V)$.